# SmartCard Certificate with Java applet and SilverLight

Tags: java, c#, silverlight, applet, smartcard

I don't have much experience as a developper and my boss put me a challange bigger than what I can achieve.
I feel a bit lost because when i graduated this technology was already obsolete, so I know almost nothing about them!

**The big problem is:**
I have a very complex website developped with SilverLight and I need to use a smartCard to digitally sign a XML inside the silverlight. Knowing, after a bit of searching, that silverlight can't do it, I told my boss that it is not possible to do. My boss insists and suggested me to use a java applet to help to solve this problem but I am lost in here...

Is that possible? Is possible to use a Java Applet to sign the XML and return it to SilverLight? Can someone give some help with this?

Thankyou!

P.S. None of the developpers that developped the silverlight website is woring in this company anymore, so I don't have any kind of help from more experienced developpers...

Comment: http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/10936_3587361_4/Java-Applet-for-Signing-with-a-Smart-Card.htm

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581705/xml-signing-with-remote-applet-devices

hi there try these sites it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Smartcards can be accessed in Silverlight5 pretty easily via [Pkcs11Interop](https://pkcs11interop.net/) library (which I am the author of) but there are two limitations:

- your application requires [elevated trust](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg192793%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)
- it works only on Windows (because elevated trust apps are not supported on Mac OS X)